# Specify culture for application c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

my computer is set to america datetime culture `dd-mm-yyyy` but in my application I want to use `yy-mm-dd` so I want to use swedish culture no matter what the computer culture is set to. using this line dosen't always work `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("sv-SE");`
It's a asp.net web application.

Comment: Doesn't always work - what's the issue you're facing?

Comment: Sometimes when debugging my datetime will be dd-mm-yyyy and the next time I debug the same datetime will be yyyy-mm-dd.

Comment: @JoakimCarlsson Are you sure it is after setting a culture for a `Thread`?

Comment: @Kamo it works when not debugging, but when debugging it doesn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Setting the culture for the thread only works for code executed after that line. Also a request can be handled by different threads in different stages, so you would need to repeat that line after each point where a thread switch is possible.

To set the culture globally you can specify the culture in the `system.web` section in `web.config`:

```
<globalization culture="sv-SE" uiCulture="sv-SE" />
```

Comment: Thanks, this would have helped be a long time ago. Thanks for the fast reply.